# Making programs use internet proxy settings

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-firewall

I have a work laptop where everything connecting to the internet goes through a proxy, which is :.  The only applications that work are Internet Explorer and Chrome.  I downloaded cygwin, and was able to get it to download all the packages I wanted by selecting  "Use internet explorer proxy settings".  Now the issue is after it downloaded I can no longer access the internet from cygwin.  I have tried setting the environment variables:

```
export http_proxy=<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export HTTP_PROXY=<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export proxy=<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export PROXY=<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export FTP_PROXY=<proxy address>:<proxy port>
```

I also tried doing:

```
export http_proxy=<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export HTTP_PROXY=<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export proxy=<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export PROXY=<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>
export FTP_PROXY=<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>
```

But this did not fix the problem ping, wget, lynx, and all other programs which access the internet do not work.  Also applications such as Spotify don't work, the package downloader for the text editor Atom doesn't work, eclipse package downloader doesn't work, and the only thing that works is internet explorer and chrome (which are both using the internet explorer proxy settings).  Also ping on the windows cmd doesn't work.  So my question is how do I get all these applications to use the proxy?  I was thinking of creating a process which takes the outgoing packets from each application, and forward them through the proxy, but there must be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

This would normally be the syntax:

```
export http_proxy=http://10.9.8.7:1234/
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

for applications such as wget

`ping` won't be routed through a proxy